# Linking stylesheet with base_url() in CI gives blank page?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to create a header template in Codeigniter and link stylesheet with the base_url() function, but when I do that I get a blank page. This is my code:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/front/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/front/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

If I remove

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/front/
```

I don't have a blank page, but obviously the style is broken.

I'm loading the url helper in autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

so that shouldn't be an issue.

I also double-checked my base_url in config.php, it's ok.

I don't know if the location is the issue.? The assets folder is in the root of the app, outside the 'application' folder.

And also I'm not sure whether the .htaccess file could cause this issue. This is how it looks:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Use `site_url()` instead of `base_url()`, and make sure css file path is correct*

*Links should be like this :*

```
<link href="<?=site_url('assets/front/css/style.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="<?=site_url('assets/front/css/responsive.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

For more :https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: did my answer helps you? did u checked it?